# Maintain current form state in scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to implement a check with Angularjs when logging out of my application to see if the current form is $dirty.

The logout button is in a different form and not within the same scope of the form that I want to check if it's dirty.

Is there a way that add or maintain the from state in a global scope so it can be checked while logging out?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way you could iterate through all scopes, or otherwise find all instances of [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: Something like document.querySelectorAll('form.ng-dirty'); ?

Comment: No, that's a DOM operation. I was thinking of something on the *model* side of things. But what you suggest also sounds feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the state of your form in the $rootScope, he is available in the entire application :

```
$rootScope.formState = yourFormName.$dirty;
```

And you can check the $rootScope after the logout.

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Is there a way to automate this assignment? Otherwise I'd need to assign it manually on every controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i found no way for automate this assignment because you're assignment is based on a DOM state and you need to wait the load of the page for make this assignment, therefor something like the `$routeprovider` with a resolve for all routes can't work.